# Bower generating wrong path, inserting extra token

Tags: bower, userapp

In my bower.json, I have this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    /* (... many omitted...) */
    "userapp": "~2.0.0",
    "userapp-angular": "~2.0.4"
  },
```

By default, when running a `grunt bowerInstall` task, inside of `index.html` this is mis-generated like this:

```
<script src="../bower_components/useruserapp.client.js"></script>
```

Notice the spurious extra "user" bit right after `bower_components/`.

So going back into `bower.json` I added this bit:

```
  "overrides": {
    "userapp": {
      "main": "./userapp.client.js"
    },
```

Which results in the same.

Where is this extra `user` token coming from, and how can I make bower generate the path correctly?  This only takes place for this one component.   Bower correctly generates paths for about a dozen other components, including for the other one I listed here:

```
<script src="../bower_components/userapp-angular/angularjs.userapp.js"></script>
```

Don't know if this is related or not, but `bower_components/userapp/bower.json` looks legit except for one item: in its own bower.json, it self-reports as version 1.2.3 although I installed it from my bower.json as 2.0.0.